# Custom User Agent for a WebView

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

can I set a custom User Agent for a `WebView`?

I need to show mobile style of websites.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to do:

```
string ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X)" + "AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25";
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(url));
httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent",ua);
webView1.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(hrm);
```

Answer (score 2):

Per this [MSDN Forum posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/ea00647f-ba00-45a0-8df0-fa267f073ab9) you cannot.  Could you host a lightweight proxy service (say Azure Web Site) to proxy the request for you?

Comment: Thanks Jim.
Yeah, using a proxy is a solution of course. I was wondering if I can manage that without using one.

Answer (score 2):

You can load HTML with custom user agent and then pass the html to `WebView`

**Loading html**

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler {AllowAutoRedirect = false};
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent",
                                 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; 
                                  WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**assign html to `WebView`**

```
WebView.NavigateToString(html);
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the first thing that came to my mind, actually. But it became a serious pain. The user is not able to navigate or anything. And for some websites you will need to set much more than just User-Agent.