# Windows 8 App - Webview control (C#). Injecting JavaScript to change User Agent string

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm trying to change the User Agent of a Webview in a Windows 8 app. At the moment, I'm currently doing this:

```cs
    [DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(int dwOption, 
    string pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);
    const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;
```

Then if I needed to change the UA to the iPhone for example:

```cs
            string ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X)" + 
"AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25";
            UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, ua, ua.Length, 0);
```

This works perfectly. But unfortunately, if I'm going to submit this app to the Windows Store, I won't be able to use this method since *UrlMkSetSessionOption* is not officially supported in Windows 8 apps.

Upon searching for alternatives I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13775640/1949034). However, although that works, the page renders horribly, with barely any images or other elements being shown.

So I hoped that another way to do this would be by using the *WebView.InvokeScript* method and injecting some JavaScript to change the UA. The problem being, to be quite honest, is that I'm a complete beginner when it comes to JavaScript.

I did a bit more searching and apparently something like this ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1307088/1949034)) would work:

```js
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function(){
return 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25' // customized user agent
});

navigator.userAgent; // 'foo'
```

But like I said, I'm a complete beginner with Javascript. So when exactly should I inject the code? Do I need to listen for an event in JavaScript that runs this code when it fires?

Comment: Tha JS solution can't work IMHO since UserAgent ist already sent with the first HTTP GET going to the server - long before ANY JS is executed!

Comment: Are you sure? This is where I found the JS code, and according to those users it seemed to work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1307088/1949034

Comment: Yes I am sure... the solution works for "JS unit testing" - i.e. inside the page when running JS - it can't (by definition) work before any HTML/JS is even received... the browser sends a user agent in HTTP request which happens BEFORE any JS can even run!

Comment: Ok, I understand. I guess I'll have to wait until there's an official WinRT supported solution available. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

it's easy.

```
 string ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X)" + "AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25";
            Uri targetUri = new Uri(url);
            HttpRequestMessage hrm=new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,targetUri);
            hrm.Headers.Add("User-Agent",ua);
            webView1.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(hrm);
```

Comment: Would this also work for all subsequest requests? I mean all the calls for .js, .css, .json and so on